# Angular 2 -- Primeng Carousel Failing

Tags: angular, primeng

I am implementing Primeng carousel and getting the error shown below.

Mark up:

```
<p-carousel [value]="products" numVisible="4" 
      responsive="true" circular="circular" autoplayInterval="3000">
      <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
              <a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/{{product.image[0]}}" 
                width="220">
            <br><br>
            <p class="wordshortened"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></p>
            </a>
              <p-rating [(ngModel)]="product.rating" readonly="true" [cancel]="false" stars="5">
              </p-rating>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
```

Error: I have implemented this code precisely as shown above previously and did not encounter this error.

```
Carousel.html:24 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEmbeddedView' of undefined
at ViewContainerRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.es5.js:10041)
at TemplateWrapper.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/common/shared.js.TemplateWrapper.ngOnInit (shared.js:69)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10843)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (Carousel.html:24)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
enter code here
```

Comment: what is the version of angualr you are using ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Angular version 4.4.6